# How to use Elasticsearch FunctionScore query using Java API

Tags: elasticsearch, java

I need to implement the below function_score query using Java APIs. I couldn't find any official documentation for function_score query in the Java API section of elasticsearch

```
{
  "size": 40,
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "functions": [
        {
          "gauss": {
            "location": {
              "origin": {
                "lat": 39.99606,
                "lon": 116.480484
              },
              "offset": "2km",
              "scale": "3km"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "score_mode": "sum",
      "boost_mode": "replace",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "range": {
                "startTime": {
                  "from": "2016-04-12T12:00:00.000Z",
                  "to": "2016-04-12T16:00:00.000Z",
                  "include_lower": true,
                  "include_upper": true
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "range": {
                "endTime": {
                  "from": "2016-04-12T12:00:00.000Z",
                  "to": "2016-04-12T16:00:00.000Z",
                  "include_lower": true,
                  "include_upper": true
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I use the Java api like this

```
RangeQueryBuilder queryStartDate = QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("startTime").gte(param.getStartTime())
                .lte(param.getEndTime());

        RangeQueryBuilder queryEndDate = QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("endTime").gte(param.getStartTime())
                .lte(param.getEndTime());

// query
QueryBuilder querys = QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(queryStartDate).must(queryEndDate);

// function
Map<String, Double> locationMap = new HashMap<String, Double>();
        locationMap.put("lat", param.getLat());
        locationMap.put("lon", param.getLng());
        ScoreFunctionBuilder sfb2 = ScoreFunctionBuilders.gaussDecayFunction("location", locationMap, "1km")
                .setOffset("2km");

//function_score
FunctionScoreQueryBuilder sa = new FunctionScoreQueryBuilder().boostMode("replace").add(sfb2);

//final search
SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch().setIndices("film").setTypes("data").setQuery(sa)
                .setQuery(querys).setSize(40).execute().actionGet();
```

but it dose not work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add your query in your `FunctionScoreQueryBuilder` as below :

```
    FunctionScoreQueryBuilder fqBuilder = QueryBuilders.functionScoreQuery(querys);
    fqBuilder.boostMode(CombineFunction.REPLACE);
    fqBuilder.scoreMode(ScoreMode.Sum.name().toLowerCase());
    fqBuilder.add(sfb2);
    SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch().setIndices("film").setTypes("data").setQuery(fqBuilder).setSize(40).execute().actionGet();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me, it works,and I want to know how to find the elasticsearch java-api documentation? I can not find the official documentation, something like CombineFunction.REPLACE, I even do not know the const parameter...

Comment: If you just look at the api doc, you can easily find it. Just look into the class and you will find an api with signature : public FunctionScoreQueryBuilder boostMode(CombineFunction combineFunction)

Comment: This answer should be edited. As @USML mentioned in the answer below FunctionScoreQueryBuilder.add() was removed.

Comment: prepareSearch is not available in recent version of RestHighLevelClient

Answer (score 5):

In ElasticSearch 5.x this has been changed, and `FunctionScoreQueryBuilder.add()` method is no longer there (removed, not deprecated). This page has some example: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-compound-queries.html#java-query-dsl-function-score-query